# SQLite -- summing values in a case expression within a select

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I'm trying to get a sum from a case in line 4. I've tried wrapping the case in sum, having sum around `s.qty`, but nothing is working.

```
select s.part,
max(case s.location when 'stock' then s.qty else 0 end) qty_stock,
max(case s.location when 'material' then s.qty else 0 end) qty_material,
case s.location when not 'stock' or 'material' then s.qty else 0 end qty_wip

from stock as s

group by s.part
```

output

```
Part        qty_stock qty_material qty_wip
"Part 1"    "10"      "25"         "0"
"Part 2"    "12"      "0"          "0"
"Part 3"    "14"      "0"          "0"
"Part 4"    "16"      "0"          "0"
"Part 5"    "0"       "0"          "0"
"Part 6"    "0"       "0"          "0"
```

Any help gladly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `sum()` instead :

```
select s.part,
       sum(case when s.location = 'stock' then s.qty else 0 end) as qty_stock,
       sum(case when s.location = 'material' then s.qty else 0 end) as qty_material,
       sum(case when s.location not in ('stock', 'material') then s.qty else 0 end) as qty_wip
from stock as s
group by s.part;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Yogesh!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select s.part,
       max(case s.location when 'stock' then s.qty else 0 end) as qty_stock,
       max(case s.location when 'material' then s.qty else 0 end) as qty_material,
       sum(case when s.location not in ('stock', 'material') then s.qty else 0 end ) as qty_wip
from stock as s
group by s.part;
```

Your problem is the `case` expression itself.  Using a full condition should fix the issue.

Comment: What do you mean Gordon?

Comment: @S1M0N_H . . . Your `case` expression is the problem in your query, not the aggregation function.  Look at what the `case` is in this answer (and in Yogesh's answer, which was two minutes later).